# Which target framework should I choose for library project in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

My current mindset is to use .NET Standard x.x for libraries and concrete frameworks for *executable* projects. So with this in mind let's say I have one common (fictional) project `Common.csproj`

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net5.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net5.0'">
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation" Version="9.5.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'">
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation" Version="8.6.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

One library project `Lib.csproj`

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="Common.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

And one executable project `Cli.csproj`

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="Lib.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

So, in this case if `FluentValidation` library has different method signatures in different versions, compilation in some cases goes thru, but you get error at runtime.

What are the recommendations for cases like this? Should I just support all needed target frameworks in `Lib.csproj`?

Comment: The same version (x.x) of FluentValidation should have the same API, same method signatures etc. irrespective of the target framework setting. I think you're worrying about this unnecessarily.

Comment: Different version of `FluentValidation` have different method signatures. In this case 9.5.4 have some different method signatures than 8.6.0.

Comment: All projects should reference the same version though. Not sure why you'd want to reference different ones!

Comment: Legacy issues :/

Comment: Can you just target the lower version or not?

Comment: Also .Net 5 can consume .Net Standard 2.0 projects

Comment: I think you don't understand the problem... And this question it more conceptual than concrete. What I did now is that I added support for net5 to lib.csproj. This technically solves the problem, but it does not solve it in conceptual way because in this case .NET Standard is not important anymore and you need to be aware of all supported frameworks of base library. And I am not the owner of base library.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you're after is using pre-processor directives with target frameworks:

```cs
#if NETSTANDARD
    // Code targeting .Net Standard
#elif NET
    // Code targetting .Net Core / .Net
#elif NETFRAMEWORK
    // Code targetting .Net Framework
#endif
```

You can get as specific as you like i.e. targeting .Net Standard 2.0 exactly:

```
#if NETSTANDARD2_0
   // .Net Standard 2.0 specific code
#elif
   // anything else!
#endif
```

This will let `Common.csproj` use the correct method calls for the appropriate version of FluentValidation that you need.

Personally, I find it a little messy - but sometimes, needs must.